# False positive rate with CRC

Tags: math, forward-error-correction

What is the technique to calculate the false positive rate for an N-bit CRC?

Example: Communication system sends M-bit packets with a N-bit CRC (M >> N) appended to each packet. What is the probability that the CRC passes, but it's actually a false pass (i.e., bc of bit errors)

Answer (score 2):

The CRC code is linear, so if you $w_0, w_1 \in \mathcal{C}$, then $w_0 \oplus w_1 \in \mathcal{C}$. The event you described, the false pass, means that you transmitted $w_0$ and received $w_1$, and the bits in error are given by $w = w_0 \oplus w_1$.

Where $|w|$ denodes the codeword hamming weight (number of 1's), for a BSC channel with error probability $p_e$.

$$\sum_{w \in \mathcal C} (1-p_e)^{M - |w|} p_e^{|w|}$$

Or
$$P_{ue}(p_e) = \sum_{d=0}^M A_j(1-p_e)^{M - j} p_e^{j}$$

Where $A_i$ is the number of codewords with weight $i$.

Here is something I found googling your question
https://www.ieee802.org/3/bv/public/Jan_2015/perezaranda_3bv_2_0115.pdf

The answer is, it is a hard problem...

One thing is that for low $p_e$ the terms of the summation for $P_{ue}(p_e)$ are dominated by the small weight words, thus it could be approximated by $P_{ue}(p_e) \le A_d (1-p_e)^{M-d}p_e^d$

You can find [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0607068.pdf) claims that you can solve this problem with complexity linear with the size of the packet $n$ in the formula

$$\mathcal{O}\left( p^{\delta r} \delta r t^2 n \right).$$

Where field characteristic $q=p^\delta=2^1$ is the field characteristic, and $r$ is the length of the CRC (e.g. 32). But to be honest this seems too complex unless you need this for a serious application.

#### A more straightforward approach.

Since we are interested only in the number of low-weight words.

let $m_i$ be the i-th weight 1 message, let $\mathrm{CRC}(m)$ be the redundancy bits appended to the message to produce the codeword.

Then let $z_{1,u}=1$ for these code words ($u$ will be unique if you don't exceed the period of the CRC).

Then you compute
$$z_{k+1, u} = - (k-1) z_{k-1, u} + \sum z_{k,u \oplus v} z_{1, v}$$

The term $(k-1) z_{k-1, u}$ compensates the terms where a bit of the message was cleared instead of the set.

This has complexity $\mathcal{O}(M 2^r)$ per iteration, but the sum can be computed using the Hadamard transform reducing it to $\mathcal{O}(r 2^r)$ time and $\mathcal{O}(2^r)$ space. Struggling a little you can fit solve the problem for a 28-bit CRC using 1GB RAM.

Once you have computed $z$ you can get the weight distribution as $A_j = \sum z_{j-|u|, u}$